# how to fix hover option working on the whole row

Tags: html, css

I just started making a website for practicing and learning html and css, and i made like a about button on the top right so when you hover over it it displays information, but the hover function works all over the left row of the website.

HTML:

```
<div class="position">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  margin-left: 1370px;   
}

/* The container <div> */
.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #2841d1;
  min-width: 160px;
  max-width: 333px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: 1140px;
}

/* Text inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content h4 {
  color: black;
  padding:15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown: hover .dropdown-content {display: inline-block;}

.position{
    position: relative;
}
.dropdown-content,h4{
    width: 40%;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Sorry for the bad code i just started learning html and css

Comment: Are you wanting the text to appear full-screen and not right under the button on the right side of the site?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem might be that you have `hover` on `.dropdown` (which is the whole row), instead of on `.dropdown-content`.

You are talking about a hover `function`, which is javascript, and there's no javascript, so I'm not sure.

You have

```
.dropdown: hover .dropdown-content {display: inline-block;}
```

1. hover on the wrong item
2. missing comma
3. extra space (not sure if that's a problem).

Update

```
.dropdown, .dropdown-content:hover { display: inline-block; }
```

(I think something else might be missing from your problem-description, or code.)

Comment: thank you for you r answer, i copied the code from a website and just edited it  to my liking but as i see there are a lot of problems so i will just write my own code.

Comment: If this is not for school, make sure you look at [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/). It has a lot of stuff built in.

Comment: it's not for school, and i will look into bootstrap

Comment: Though be aware that Bootstrap promotes a **Utility CSS** approach which entails adopting the opposite **dependency-direction** from the conventional one (ie. in Bootstrap, HTML classes reference pre-written groups of CSS styles rather then the more conventional approach where CSS styles are written and grouped under pre-established HTML classes).